# Oracle SQL for BOM Extended Quantity

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

Looking to build a query to display the extended quantity from multiple-level hierarchical data.

I have a bill of materials (BOM) table that defines the relationship of an assembly, the parts it contains, and the quantity of each part.  Each part can be a sub-assembly that is also defined as an expression of parts and quantity.  In the table below, Item0 contains one quantity of Item1 -- Item1 contains contains two items: one quantity of Item3 and two quantities of Item6 -- and so on.

Using Oracle's hierarchical query features, I was successful in writing a query that explodes all the sub-items for a given item but I could use some help trying to calculate the extended quantity.

SQL Fiddle with example schema and hierarchical query: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5217c/1

Here is my source table:

```
+------------+-----------+----------+
| PARENTNODE | CHILDNODE | QUANTITY |
+------------+-----------+----------+
| Item0      | Item1     |        2 |
| Item0      | Item5     |        1 |
| Item0      | Item6     |        2 |
| Item0      | Item7     |        2 |
| Item0      | Item9     |      384 |
| Item1      | Item3     |        1 |
| Item1      | Item6     |        2 |
| Item3      | Item11    |        1 |
| Item3      | Item14    |        1 |
| Item3      | Item15    |        1 |
| Item3      | Item16    |        3 |
| Item3      | Item17    |        1 |
| Item3      | Item18    |        1 |
| Item3      | Item19    |        1 |
| Item3      | Item21    |        1 |
| Item4      | Item20    |        1 |
| Item4      | Item23    |        0 |
| Item4      | Item24    |        1 |
| Item4      | Item8     |        1 |
| Item5      | Item22    |        4 |
| Item5      | Item4     |        4 |
| Item6      | Item10    |        0 |
| Item6      | Item13    |        1 |
| Item6      | Item9     |       32 |
| Item7      | Item12    |        1 |
| Item7      | Item9     |       16 |
+------------+-----------+----------+
```

And my desired output is something like below; however, the 'multiple' field is provided to show how the extended quantity was found and isn't a requirement:

```
+------------+-----------+-----+----------+--------+--------------------+
| PARENTNODE | CHILDNODE | Qty | Multiple | ExtQty |        Path        |
+------------+-----------+-----+----------+--------+--------------------+
| Item0      | Item1     |   2 |        1 |      2 | /Item0             |
| Item0      | Item10    |   0 |        2 |      0 | /Item0/Item1/Item6 |
| Item0      | Item10    |   0 |        4 |      0 | /Item0/Item1/Item6 |
| Item0      | Item11    |   1 |        2 |      2 | /Item0/Item1/Item3 |
| Item0      | Item12    |   1 |        2 |      2 | /Item0/Item7       |
| Item0      | Item13    |   1 |        2 |      2 | /Item0/Item1/Item6 |
| Item0      | Item13    |   1 |        4 |      4 | /Item0/Item1/Item6 |
| Item0      | Item14    |   1 |        2 |      2 | /Item0/Item1/Item3 |
| Item0      | Item15    |   1 |        2 |      2 | /Item0/Item1/Item3 |
| Item0      | Item16    |   3 |        2 |      6 | /Item0/Item1/Item3 |
| Item0      | Item17    |   1 |        2 |      2 | /Item0/Item1/Item3 |
| Item0      | Item18    |   1 |        2 |      2 | /Item0/Item1/Item3 |
| Item0      | Item19    |   1 |        2 |      2 | /Item0/Item1/Item3 |
| Item0      | Item20    |   1 |        4 |      4 | /Item0/Item5/Item4 |
| Item0      | Item21    |   1 |        2 |      2 | /Item0/Item1/Item3 |
| Item0      | Item22    |   4 |        1 |      4 | /Item0/Item5       |
| Item0      | Item23    |   0 |        4 |      0 | /Item0/Item5/Item4 |
| Item0      | Item24    |   1 |        4 |      4 | /Item0/Item5/Item4 |
| Item0      | Item3     |   1 |        2 |      2 | /Item0/Item1       |
| Item0      | Item4     |   4 |        1 |      4 | /Item0/Item5       |
| Item0      | Item5     |   1 |        1 |      1 | /Item0             |
| Item0      | Item6     |   2 |        1 |      2 | /Item0/Item1       |
| Item0      | Item6     |   2 |        2 |      4 | /Item0/Item1       |
| Item0      | Item7     |   2 |        1 |      2 | /Item0             |
| Item0      | Item8     |   1 |        4 |      4 | /Item0/Item5/Item4 |
| Item0      | Item9     |  16 |        2 |     32 | /Item0/Item1/Item6 |
| Item0      | Item9     | 384 |        1 |    384 | /Item0/Item1/Item6 |
| Item0      | Item9     |  32 |        2 |     64 | /Item0/Item1/Item6 |
| Item0      | Item9     |  32 |        4 |    128 | /Item0/Item1/Item6 |
+------------+-----------+-----+----------+--------+--------------------+
```

Any help is appreciate

Comment: Accidentally deleted a comment.  Explaining the multiple logic:

Looking at the results from that SQL Fiddle and focusing on Item24 in CHILDNOTE, we see that Item24's path contains Item0, Item5, and Item4.  Item0's quantity is 1, Item5's quantity is 1, and Item4's quantity is 4.  So the multiple is 1 X 1 X 4 = 4.

I've updated the above desired solution table to display the hierarchy path.

Comment: For extended quantity you can try `quantity * nvl(prior quantity, 1)`. It does not give always values which are in your column ExtQty, but I'm not sure this data is correct everywhere. Anyway - worth try.

Comment: Looks like using `quantity * nvl(prior quantity, 1)` works when the item is only one level below the top level item but not when it's 2+ levels below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This recursive query gives desired output:

```
with r(parentnode, childnode, quantity, eq, pth) as (
  select parentnode, childnode, quantity, quantity eq, '/'||parentnode 
    from exampletable where parentnode='Item0'
  union all
  select e.parentnode, e.childnode, e.quantity, 
      e.quantity * r.eq eq, r.pth||'/'||e.childnode
    from exampletable e, r
    where e.parentnode = r.childnode)
select * from r order by childnode;
```

Comment: If you want explanation, here: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483435/view-requires-interdependence-logic-possible-without-model) is good example to see. There are also many other examples on SO and on the net.